# Есть ли аналоги JSON Crack для визуализации структур в С\С++?

Tags: c++, c

Есть довольно большой проект, где очень много структур в структурах и еще в структурах. Хотелось бы попробовать нечто визуальное (вдруг будет удобнее), аналогичное Json Crack.

Comment: В Visual Studio есть встроенный визуализатор классов.